# previous activity's method being called again onBackPress

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Screenshot 1 - https://ibb.co/k5O8Eo

Screenshot 2 - https://ibb.co/bz5MZo

Screenshot one is how its supposed to behave and it does behave like that when I open it... but after I open the activity and go to the next activity and come back... the same messages are being fetched again and showing twice although only in the database its only once... how do I solve this problem?

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    fetchMessages();
}

private void fetchMessages() {
   mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Messages message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
            messagesList.add(message);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably happening because your activity is in backstack and every time you come back the `onStart` method is called which results in multiple fetches.

You can clear the list in `onStop()`

```
 @Override
 public void onStop(){
 if(messagesList != null){
   messageList.clear();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are calling `fetchMessages()` method from inside the `onStart()` method, which means that each you stop and then start the activity, this method is triggered and you are ending up in having duplicate data.

To solve this, move the call of the method in the `onCreate()` method so you'll have the data displayed only once even if you are returning from another activity or if the `onBackPress()` method is called.

Answer (score 0):

You call `fetchMessages()` every time your activity starts, and in that you add a listener to Firebase. This means that the second time the activity is started, you end up adding a second listener. So at that point you'll receive the data from Firebase twice.

The solution is to remove the listener in the corresponding lifecycle method. Since you add the listener in `onStart`, you should remove it in `onStop`:

```
public void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
   mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).removeChildEvenListener(mListener);
}
```

You'll note that we need a `mListener` in here, so you'll need to capture that in `onStart`:

```
mListener = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  ...
```